# SSRS Nested Report Not Coming Through if Dataset is Empty

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, null, ssrs-2008, subreport

I'm working with a pre-existing SSRS report that has a nested sub report.

The nested sub report doesn't always return data. (and this is correct). If the data set is empty nothing comes through no report or column headers no values of any kind no logos. Nothing. However, that is not what we want. If the data set is empty the report should return the headers/logo's and column headings with a string that states there is no data for this data range.

There are no filters/visibility settings preventing it from coming through. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a "dummy" record if there's no data. Say your current query is:

```
SELECT ID
    , [Name]
    , [FavoriteFruit]
FROM yourTable
WHERE [SomeField] = 'hello'
```

You can check for values and return a dummy record like:

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE [SomeField] = 'hello'
    )
    SELECT ID
        , [Name]
        , [FavoriteFruit]
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE [SomeField] = 'hello'
ELSE
    SELECT ID = 0
        , [Name] = 'No data'
```

Comment: I don't have control over the data, and thus inserting a dummy record won't work. but i like the idea about checking if there is data. that said the syntax above is SQL not ssrs syntax. where/how would i use the above logic to test for records in ssrs

Comment: It's not actually inserting a record - bad wording on my part. This is altering the report's Data Source query to include a dummy record: it doesn't have to be in the database because you're just specifying values to return. You can include IF/THEN logic in a report's query.

Comment: It also occurred to me that you could include a whole dummy tablix control. Create a new Data Source with the query "SELECT ID = 1". That query will always return "1" as a value for [ID], so the report should always generate normally. Just make sure you make the dummy tablix small and set the font to while so the user never sees it.

Comment: got it. will try this. thanks. (the question i have still stands why the data isn't coming through/visible) and while this option ill test to see if i can use it. i don't understand why column headers are not coming through when nested.

Answer (score 1):

Check for `Row Exists`

```
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table)
     BEGIN
          SELECT Column from table
     END        
  ELSE
     BEGIN
          SELECT 'No records' as Column from table
     END
```

Add a condition for your result Table from SSRS report

`Tablix Properties > Visibility > Show or Hide Based on Condition`

Add a `TextBox` with text `'No records found'` and add a condition to show based on your Dataset result.

Comment: Just to make sure this is SQL not SSRS syntax? also will this display the headers/etc. I still can't get those to show.

Answer (score 0):

Had that happen also with a Sub-Sub-Report. Once there are 0 Lines in the Dataset, the whole Sub-Sub-Report is not rendered.
I love SSRS for those *easy to find* errors...
I've just added the following to the original query

```
[..]Original SQL-Query[..]
UNION ALL
SELECT null,null,null,null,...
```